403 error when uploading podcast episode to Buzzsprout API
Wrote the following Python script but getting a 422 error
import requests

url = "https://www.buzzsprout.com/api/******/episodes.json"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Token token=********",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}

# Define the path to your file
audio_file_path = "*************************"

# Open the file in binary mode
with open(audio_file_path, "rb") as f:
# Define the files parameter for the post request
files = {"audio_file": f}

# Define the data to be sent in the POST request
data = {
    "title": "Too many or too few?",
    "description": "",
    "explicit": False,
    "private": True,
    "email_user_after_audio_processed": True,
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, files=files)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Episode created successfully.")
else:
    print("Failed to create episode. Status code:", response.status_code)
    with open('error.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(response.content.decode('utf-8'))

I'm able to fetch episodes from the API just fine, so I know the API key is working, but consistently get a 422 whenever I try to POST a new episode.
API docs for reference: https://github.com/buzzsprout/buzzsprout-api/tree/master

Is the error 403 or 422? If it's 403, you might be blocked by Cloudflare. In that case, try setting a unique value for the 'User-Agent' in the request header. This resolved the 403 error for me.

I've been having code that used to work just fine start failing for the past month or two.
Seems like Buzzsprout has neglected their service so badly they don't even realize their API is down

I also have a very stable upload pipeline to the Buzzsprout API that recently stopped working. Seems like a new rule got rolled out and Cloudflare is blocking requests to this API that do not have User-Agent defined in the header.
To your headers section, go ahead and add a user-agent and you should be back up and running.
